# Find the minumum of the value $k$ such two condition $x_1+x_2+ \cdots +x_k<\frac{x_1^3+x_2^3+ \cdots +x_k^3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_k$ be positive real numbers satisfying
\begin{cases} x_1+x_2+ \cdots +x_k<\frac{x_1^3+x_2^3+ \cdots +x_k^3}{2};\\ x_1^2+x_2^2+ \cdots +x_k^2<\frac{x_1+x_2+ \cdots +x_k}{2}.\end{cases} Find minimal value of $k$ satisfying those equations.

It is said this problem creat  Kvant? And the answer is $k_{\min}=516$. See here :[hard inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1217932p6073535).

**ADD it** Michael Rozenberg take this problem   from the 28-th Tournament of Towns, autumn 2006, problem 7 and he say maybe it is open problem in Canada.

when $k=516$,I found this example such condition
$$x_{1}=5.169,x_{2}=x_{3}=\cdots=x_{516}=\dfrac{1}{8}$$
because
$$x^2_{1}+x^2_{2}+\cdots+x^2_{516}=5.169^2+\dfrac{515}{64}=34.765436,$$$$~~\dfrac{1}{2}(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{516})=\dfrac{1}{2}(5.169+\dfrac{515}{8})=34.772$$
and

$$(x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{516})=(5.169+\dfrac{515}{8})=69.544$$
$$\dfrac{1}{2}(x^3_{1}+x^3_{2}+\cdots+x^3_{516})=\dfrac{1}{2}(5.169^3+\dfrac{515}{512})=69.557050592$$

Comment: Updated revision

Answer (score 3):

We reorder the set to $x_1\ge x_2\ge\dots\ge x_k$. If all $0\lt x_j\lt\sqrt{2}$ 
then the inequality

$$\tag{1}x_1+\dots+x_k\lt\dfrac{x_1^3+\dots+x_k^3}{2}$$

does not hold. Therefore $x_1\ge\sqrt{2}$. If all $x_j\gt\dfrac{1}{2}$ then the inequality

$$\tag{2}x_1^2+\dots+x_k^2\lt\dfrac{x_1+\dots+x_k}{2}$$

does not hold. Therefore $0\lt x_k\le\dfrac{1}{2}$ and we get $k\gt1$. For $x_j\gt0$ we have $\dfrac{x_j}{2}-x_j^2\le\dfrac{1}{16}$, the value increases for $x_j\le\dfrac{1}{4}$ with growing $x_j$, the value decreases for $x_j\ge\dfrac{1}{4}$ with growing $x_j$ and the inequality $(2)$ does not hold if $x_1\gt 2k$. Therefore the parameters $(x_j)_j$ are bounded.

For any solution $\hat x_1,\dots,\hat x_k$ we have $\hat x_1\ge\sqrt{2}$ and therefore we can increase $\hat x_1$ and the inequality $(1)$ still holds. But in increasing $\hat x_1$ we will finally get an equality in the inequality $(2)$ and therefore there exists a set $(\hat x_j)_j$ such that

$$\tag{3}\hat x_1^2+\dots+\hat x_k^2=\dfrac{\hat x_1+\dots+\hat x_k}{2}$$

is true. Hence we will find the maximum

$$\tag{4}f((x_j)_j):=f(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\sum_{j=1}^k\left\{\dfrac{x_j^3}{2}-x_j\right\}$$

under the condition $(3)$

$$\tag{5}g((x_j)_j):=g(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\sum_{j=1}^k\left\{\dfrac{x_j}{2}-x_j^2\right\}=0.$$

Because the $x_j$ are bounded and the set defined by $(5)$ is closed, the maximum of the function $f((x_j)_j)$ exists. With the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ we define

$$\tag{6}F((x_j)_j,\lambda):=f((x_j)_j)+\lambda g((x_j)_j).$$

The maximum can only exists at points where the equalities

$$\tag{7}\dfrac{\partial F((x_j)_j,\lambda)}{\partial x_j}=\dfrac{3}{2}x_j^2-1+\lambda\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-2x_j\right)=0$$
$$\tag{8}\dfrac{\partial F((x_j)_j,\lambda)}{\partial\lambda}=g((x_j)_j)=0$$

hold. With $x_1\ge\sqrt{2}$ we determine the multiplier $\lambda$ to

$$\tag{9}\lambda=\dfrac{3x_1^2-2}{4x_1-1}.$$

But then the polynomials of degree $2$ for the other parameters $x_j$ in $(7)$ give either $x_1$ or a second value. We already know that there are at least two values, one less than $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and one more than $\sqrt{2}$. Therefore we rewrite the conditions $(4)$ and $(5)$ to

$$\tag{10}f(x_1,x_2):=k_1\left\{\dfrac{x_1^3}{2}-x_1\right\}+k_2\left\{\dfrac{x_2^3}{2}-x_2\right\}$$
$$\tag{11}g(x_1,x_2):=k_1\left\{\dfrac{x_1}{2}-x_1^2\right\}+k_2\left\{\dfrac{x_2}{2}-x_2^2\right\}=0$$

with $1\le k_1\lt k$ and $k_1+k_2=k$ and we will search the maximum for the functions $f(x_1,x_2)$ under the condition $g(x_1,x_2)=0$. The equation $(11)$ gives

$$\tag{12}x_2=h(x_1):=\dfrac{1}{4}\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{16}-\dfrac{k_1}{k_2}\left\{x_1^2-\dfrac{x_1}{2}\right\}}.$$

But the equation $(12)$ only gives a solution for

$$\tag{13}\dfrac{1}{4}\left\{1-\sqrt{1+\dfrac{k_2}{k_1}}\right\}\le x_1\le\dfrac{1}{4}\left\{1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac{k_2}{k_1}}\right\}=:\alpha$$

when the root in $(12)$ is not negative. If $\alpha\ge\sqrt{2}$ we have to find the maximum in the intervall $x_1\in[\sqrt{2},\alpha]$.

The function $\dfrac{x^3}{2}-x$ decreases for $0\le x\le\sqrt{{2 \over 3}}$ with growing $x$  and it increases for $x\ge\sqrt{{2 \over 3}}$ with growing $x$. If we take the positive sign in $(12)$ the function $f(x_1,x_2)$ has a value less than $f(\alpha,1/4)$ because $\alpha\ge\sqrt{2}$ and the condition $0\lt x_2\lt\dfrac{1}{2}$ for a solution. The value was always less than $0$.

For the negative sign in $(12)$ we have to find the maximum in the interval $x_1\in[\sqrt{2},\alpha]$. We do this by iteration. We start with $\xi_n=\sqrt{2}$ with $n=0$:

1. First we determine $\delta_n=\dfrac{\xi_n+\alpha}{2}$.
2. If the value $f(\xi_n, h(\xi_n))$ is more than $0$ we have found the smallest value $k$.
3. Otherwise we check whether $f(\xi_n+\delta_n, h(\xi_n))$ is less than $0$. Then the value $f(\xi_n+\delta_n, h(\xi_n+\delta_n))$ must also be less than $0$ because $x_2=h(\xi_n+\delta_n)\ge h(\xi_n)$ with $\delta_n\gt 0$ (see $(12)$) and the function $f(x_1,x_2)$ decreases for $x_2\le\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$ with growing $x_2$. Then we restart the process with $\xi_{n+1}=\xi_n+\delta_n$ at $1$.
4. Otherwise we check whether the value $f(\xi_n+\delta_n, h(\xi_n+\delta_n))$ is more than $0$. Then we have found the smallest k.
5. If all tests failed we restart at $3$ with half the value $\delta_{n}$.

The iteration either fails for a combination $k$, $k_1$ or we have found the smallest value $k$. The case that the function $f$ has a maximum of $0$  did not occur. In that case the iteration would not work.

Starting with $k=2$ and running through the values $1\le k1\lt k$ the process terminates with $k=516$, $k_1=1$, $x_1=5.13931983067114$, $x_2=0.122708944529751$.

Answer (score 2):

**Conditional extremum**

Let us maximize the function
$$f(\vec x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k(x_i^3-2x_i)$$
on the condition
$$c(\vec x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i-2x_i^2) = 0$$
for the given $k$ and positive $x_1, x_2\dots x_k.$

Note that solutions on the edges of the area reduces $k$ and therefore are unacceptable.

Also, the solution in the form
$$x_j = t,\quad j=1\dots k,$$
gives
$$t-2t^2=0\rightarrow\ t={1\over2}\rightarrow f(\vec x) = - {7\over8}k < 0$$
and isn't valid.

A conditional maximum within a region can be found by the method of Lagrange multipliers and corresponds to one of the stationary points of the function

$$f(\vec x,\lambda) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k(x_i^3-2x_i)+\lambda\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i-2x_i^2).$$
That gives the system
$$f'_\lambda =0,\quad f'_{x_j}=0,\quad j=1\dots k,$$
or
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i-2x_i^2)=0,\quad 3x_j^2-2 + \lambda(1-4x_j) = 0,\quad j=1\dots k,$$
$$3x_j^2-4\lambda x_j + \lambda -2 = 0,\quad j=1\dots k.$$

**Values Relationship**

Let $x_j \in \{u, v\},\ 0<u<v,$ then
$$u+v = {4\over3}\lambda,\quad uv = {\lambda-2\over3},$$
$$u+v = {4\over3}(3uv+2),\quad\rightarrow 12uv-3v = 3u-8,$$
$$v = {3u-8\over3(4u-1)},\quad u\in\left(0,{1\over4}\right),\quad v\in\left({8\over3}, \infty\right),$$
and substitution $t= 1-4u$ gives
$$u={1-t\over4},\quad v = {29\over12t}+{1\over4},\quad t\in(0,1)$$
Let WLOG
$$x_j = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1-t}{4},\quad j=1\dots b\\[4pt]
\dfrac{29}{12t}+\dfrac14,\quad j=b+1\dots k.
\end{cases}\tag1$$

**Solution for real parameters**

Using $(1),$ one can calculate
$$8\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i-2x_i^2) = b\left(2(1-t) - (1-t)^2\right) + (k-b)\left(2\left({29\over3t} + 1\right) - \left({29\over3t} + 1\right)^2\right) = -(k-b){841\over9t^2} + k-bt^2 = k(1-t^2) + (k-b)\left(t^2-{841\over9t^2}\right)> 0$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8b%5Cleft(%7B1-t%5Cover4%7D+-+2%7B(1-t)%5E2%5Cover16%7D%5Cright)+%2B+8(k-b)%5Cleft(%7B29%5Cover12t%7D+%2B+%7B1%5Cover4%7D+-+2%5Cleft(%7B29%5Cover12t%7D+%2B+%7B1%5Cover4%7D%5Cright)%5E2%5Cright))),
$$64\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (x_i^3-2x_i) = b((1-t)^3 - 32(1-t)) + (k-b)\left(\left({29\over3t}+1\right)^3 - 32\left({29\over3t}+1\right)\right)$$
$$ = k((1-t)^3 - 32(1-t)) + (k-b)\left(\left({29\over3t}+1\right)^3 - (1-t)^3 - 32\left({29\over3t}+1\right)+32(1-t)\right)$$
$$ = k(1-t)(-31-2t+t^2) + (k-b)\left({29\over3t}+t\right)
\left(\left({29\over3t}+1\right)^2 + \left({29\over3t}+1\right)(1-t) + (1-t)^2 - 32\right) > 0,$$
and that leads to the system of $t$ and $b$ in the form of
$$\begin{cases}
9kt^2(1-t^2) - (k-b)(841-9t^4) > 0\\
27kt^3(1-t)(-31-2t+t^2) + (k-b)(29+3t^2)(841 + 261t - 348t^2 - 27t^3 + 9t^4) > 0\\
t\in(0,1),\quad b\in[1,k-1]
\end{cases}\tag2$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9t%5E2%5Cleft(%5Cleft(%7B29%5Cover3t%7D%2B1%5Cright)%5E2%20%2B%20%5Cleft(%7B29%5Cover3t%7D%2B1%5Cright)(1-t)%20%2B%20(1-t)%5E2%20-%2032%5Cright))).

Summation of $(2.1)$ factor $\ 3t(31+2t-t^2)>0\ $ and $(2.2)$ factor $\ 1+t>0\ $ leads to the inequality for $t:$
$$(841-9t^4)3t(31+2t-t^2) - (t+1)(29+3t^2)(841+261t-348t^2-27t^3+9t^4) < 0,$$
or
$$(3t+29)(3t^2+29)(3t^2+58t-29)<0$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(841-9t%5E4)3t(31%2B2t-t%5E2)%20-%20(t%2B1)(29%2B3t%5E2)(841%2B261t-348t%5E2-27t%5E3%2B9t%5E4)%20%3C%200)),

with the solution
$$t\in(0, t_m],\quad t_m = {1\over3}(4\sqrt{58} - 29)\approx0.487697,$$
wherein $t_m$ corresponds to the equal sign of the inequalities in $(2.1)-(2.2).$

The system $(2)$ on the condition $t=t_m$ can be presented in the form of 
$$\begin{cases}
1.63149k - 840.491(k-b) > 0\\
-50.923k + 26233.9(k-b) > 0\\
b\in[1,k-1],
\end{cases}$$
$$k \approx 515,2 (k-b).$$
Solution for real $k$ and $b$ shows that the least integer allowable values are $$\mathbf{k=516,\quad b=515}.$$

**One solution for known parameters**

Earlier it was proved that solutions for $k<516$ are impossible. To find one solution in the case of known integer values $k = 516$ and $b = 515,$ one can use the relations $(1)$ in the form of
$$x_j = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1-t_m}{4},\quad j=1\dots 515\\[4pt]
\dfrac{29}{12t_m}+\dfrac14,\quad j=516\dots k,
\end{cases}$$
or
$$x_j = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{8-\sqrt{58}}{3}\approx0.12807563,\quad j=1\dots 515\\[4pt]
\dfrac{8+\sqrt{58}}{3}\approx5.20525770,\quad j=516,
\end{cases}$$
but this set [doesn't satisfy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%7B515(u%5E3-2u)%20%2B%20v%5E3-2v,%20515(u-2u%5E2)%20%2B%20v-2v%5E2%7D,%20u%20%3D(8.0-%5Csqrt%7B58%7D)%2F3,%20v%3D%20(8.0%2B%5Csqrt%7B58%7D)%2F3) the first inequality.
Substitution of
$$u_m = \dfrac{8-\sqrt{58}}{3},$$
to the first inequality 
$$515(u_m^3-2u_m) + v^3-2v > 0$$
[gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=515(u%5E3-2u)%20%2B%20v%5E3-2v%20%3E%200,%20u%3D(8.0-sqrt(58))%2F3) $v>5.20792$,
and the values $u=u_m,\ v= 5.208\ $ [give the solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%7B515(u%5E3-2u)%20%2B%20v%5E3-2v,%20515(u-2u%5E2)%20%2B%20v-2v%5E2%7D,%20u%20%3D(8.0-%5Csqrt%7B58%7D)%2F3,%20v%3D%205.208).

**The set of solutions for known parameters**

In order to find the full range of possible solutions in the case of known integer values $k = 516$ and $b = 515,$ one should abandon the relations $(1)$ and look for a solution in the form of
$$x_j = 
\begin{cases}
u,\quad j=1\dots b\\[4pt]
v,\quad j=b+1\dots k.
\end{cases}$$

Then the allowable area of $t$ can be obtained from the system
$$\begin{cases}
f(\vec x) = 515(u^3-2u) + v^3-2v > 0\\
c(\vec x) = 515(u-2u^2) + v-2v^2 >0 > 0.
\end{cases}$$

The bounds of the area can be found from the system of according equations:
$$\left[\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
515(u^3-2u) + v^3-2v > 0\\
515(u-2u^2) + v-2v^2 = 0
\end{cases}\\
&\begin{cases}
515(u^3-2u) + v^3-2v = 0\\
515(u-2u^2) + v-2v^2 > 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}\right.$$

The analysis of solutions for the [first](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=515(u%5E3-2u)+%2B+v%5E3-2v+%3E+0,+515(u-2u%5E2)+%2B+v-2v%5E2+%3D+0) and the [second](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=515(u%5E3-2u)%20%2B%20v%5E3-2v%20%3D%200,%20515(u-2u%5E2)%20%2B%20v-2v%5E2%20%3E%200) cases shows that
$$\begin{cases}
u\in(0.121883, 0.1344),\\
v\in\left(\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{-13905 u^3 + \sqrt{(27810 u - 13905 u^3)^2 - 864} + 27810 u}}{3 \sqrt[3]2}\\ 
 + \dfrac{2\sqrt[3]2}{\sqrt[3]{-13905 u^3 + \sqrt{(27810 u - 13905 u^3)^2 - 864} + 27810 u}},\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{-8240u^2 + 4120u + 1} + 1}{4}\right)
\end{cases}$$

That gives:

for $u=0.125\quad 5.16867<v<5.16967$ (see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%5Csqrt%7B-8240u%5E2%20%2B%204120u%20%2B%201%7D%20%2B%201)%2F4%3Ev%3Et%2F(3%20cbrt(2))%20%2B%202cbrt(2)%2Ft,%20t%3Dcbrt%7B-13905%20u%5E3%20%2B%20sqrt%7B(27810%20u%20-%2013905%20u%5E3)%5E2%20-%20864%7D%20%2B%2027810%20u%7D,%20%20u%20%3D%200.125)),

for $u=0.122709\quad 5.13899<v<5.13932$ (see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(%5Csqrt%7B-8240u%5E2%20%2B%204120u%20%2B%201%7D%20%2B%201)%2F4%3Ev%3Et%2F(3%20cbrt(2))%20%2B%202cbrt(2)%2Ft,%20t%3Dcbrt%7B-13905%20u%5E3%20%2B%20sqrt%7B(27810%20u%20-%2013905%20u%5E3)%5E2%20-%20864%7D%20%2B%2027810%20u%7D,%20%20u%20%3D%200.122709)), etc.

**Conclusion**

The analysis shows that
$$\boxed{k=516}$$
is the required minimum of value $k.$

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I restate the problem as follows:

Find the smallest positive integer $k$ such that there exist positive real numbers $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k$ satisfying
$2(x_1^2+x_2^2 + \cdots + x_k^2) < x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k < \frac{1}{2}(x_1^3 + x_2^3 + \cdots + x_k^3).$

My solution:

Clearly, when $k=1, 2$, impossible. In the following, assume that $k \ge 3.$

Let $y_i = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k}{2(x_1^2+x_2^2 + \cdots + x_k^2)}x_i,\ \forall i$. We have $y_i > 0,\ \forall i$ and
$2(y_1^2+y_2^2 + \cdots + y_k^2) = y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k < \frac{1}{2}(y_1^3 + y_2^3 + \cdots + y_k^3)$.

According to Vasc's Equal Variable Theorem [1, Corollary 1.9], there exist $0 < z_1 = z_2 = \cdots = z_{k-1} \le z_k$ such that
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_k,$$
$$y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \cdots + y_k^2 = z_1^2 + z_2^2 + \cdots + z_k^2,$$
$$\mathrm{and}\quad y_1^3 + y_2^3 + \cdots + y_k^3 \le z_1^3 + z_2^3 + \cdots + z_k^3.$$
Remark: Without using Equal Variable Theorem, actually it is not hard to prove this result.

Thus, it holds that
$2(z_1^2+z_2^2 + \cdots + z_k^2) = z_1 + z_2 + \cdots + z_k < \frac{1}{2}(z_1^3 + z_2^3 + \cdots + z_k^3)$.
By denoting $z_1 = z_2 = \cdots = z_{k-1}=b, \ z_k = a$, we have
$$0 < b \le a, \quad
2((k-1)b^2 + a^2) = (k-1)b + a < \frac{1}{2}((k-1)b^3 + a^3)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$b \in (0, \frac{1}{2}),\quad a = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{Q}, \quad (2b(1-2b)(k-1)-7)\sqrt{Q}
> 2b(-8b^2+6b+13)(k-1) + 7$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$b \in (0, \frac{1}{2}),\quad a = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{Q}, \quad k > \frac{2(-4b^2+2b+7)(b^2-b+2)}{b(1-2b)^3}.\qquad\qquad (3)$$
where $Q = 8b(1-2b)k + (4b-1)^2$.

Let $f(b) = \frac{2(-4b^2+2b+7)(b^2-b+2)}{b(1-2b)^3}$.
It is easy to prove that $515 < \min_{b\in (0, \frac{1}{2})} f(b) < 516$.
Thus, there exist $b\in (0, \frac{1}{2})$ and $b\le a$ satisfying (3) if and only if $k \ge 516.$
Thus, we have $k_{\min} = 516.$

Remark: When $k \ge 516$, (3) is always true by letting $b = \frac{1}{8}, \ a = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{3k+1}$.

**Reference**

[1] Vasile Cirtoaje, “The Equal Variable Method”, J. Inequal. Pure and Appl. Math., 8(1), 2007.
Online: https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf